philosophy course fallacy questions
Having a bit of trouble identifiying the fallacies in the following passages for a philosophy university course. A fallacy cannot be repeated for any of the following passages, each one is a different one. Can someone help please? Can you also provide reasoning why? Thanks a lot

Only the rich and the poor need concern the government: the rich because they try to influence legislators through the power of their wealth; the poor because they have no wealth to take care for themselves.

I disagree. The women who work in my office must be satisfied with their salaries. Not one of them has ever complained or asked for a raise.

All humans are essentially selfish—they seek their own interests. But if all humans are selfish, it follows that a welfare state cannot have broad support. A welfare state presupposes that people will be willing to share with the less fortunate rather than being selfish. So again, a welfare state cannot have broad support.



This site is not for doing your HW for you. Please outline what fallacies were covered in the course and present your reasoning attempts first.

Looks to me like the classic university humanities course game of Psychoanalyze Your Instructor And/Or The Textbook Author. The downside is that your course becomes completely worthless to your students, skills at PYIAOTTA (pronounce it Pea - Yow - Ta) being useless outside of the course itself... but at least it cuts down on the plagiarism.

I presume that what is being sought is the names of specific formulaic fallacies as being taught in that class. If so, one approach is to go through that list, decide which of them correctly describe the problem with the statement, decide which of those most correctly describes the problem, reconcile any conflicts since the homework says that each fallacy may be referenced only once, and submit the result. Since I don't know what set you have been taught, that's as far as I can take it.

(1)
"Only the rich and the poor need concern the government"
False dilemma / false dichotomy.
It is not like it doesn't concern the middle class too.
"the rich because they try to influence legislators through the power of their wealth; the poor because they have no wealth to take care for themselves."
Stereotyping, generalization fallacy.
These features do not apply to every rich or every poor person.

(2)
"The women who work in MY office must be ...."
Cherry picking as only that one office is assessed.
That one office may not be a problem, but others.

(3)
"All humans are essentially selfish—they seek their own interests."
Generalization fallacy.
Not every human is selfish all the time.
"it follows that a welfare state cannot have broad support."
non sequitur.
We understand the emergent and utilitarian advantages and disadvantages of group dynamics, separation of work, revolution etc. A welfare state is a selfish consideration. Politicians don't want to be spit on and hanged by the common people and a state in turmoil does not compete with others.

The question has the assumption that there is a fallacy in each of statements. Assuming that this is so, then to answer the question you first need to become clear about why the statement is wrong or misleading: Is there an obviously untrue premise or presupposition lurking behind it? Or is the statement simplistic, does it leave something relevant out? Is the reasoning valid (no unwarranted inferences; not circular)? Since we're often dealing with general statements -- generalizations like

people generalize too much

-- is there perhaps a counter example against them? When you do that, it's actually not so difficult to determine in which ways those statements are incorrect.
The question further asks you to label the fallacies, so to give a previously established short name to each of the errors. If you had to come up with names yourself this might be hard. But given that you may know some common names already (in fact, the course will have introduced a finite number), you can use those as hints and see which name matches which statement best. (Another hint is of course that you've been given that no fallacy is repeated.)
I actually had trouble coming up with labels for the first and second statements, though it was clear enough to me how they were incorrect (the first one due to oversimplifying the role of government, the second because  not speaking up doesn't imply being satisfied, and because of several other reasons related to this). So, I thought this might be a good test case for ChatGPT (also, I'm lazy). And indeed it was. ChatGPT came up both with obviously correct labels and a correct analysis when I fed it the complete post. -- Note that in the past I have given ChatGPT very specific instructions about how to answer questions, both as to content and style, so if you try this out and don't get an answer that is obviously correct, you will have to blame yourself...
Did you convince yourself that in the course material all the labels indeed point out "unique" fallacies? Labelling is a much more tricky, fraught business then people normally believe. Would it be possible to construct a statement or little story that combines two fallacies? (It usually is.) How about one that is in between two fallacies, neither clearly one nor the other, thus creating an ambiguity about how to label the story? -- It's only by asking yourself these kind of questions and trying to use your imagination, that you actually get an grasp on this kind of material.
An example of a statement that combines two of your fallacies in one is this:

We must either accept that all political decisions are purely self-serving, or else believe in the naïve fantasy that politicians always act in the public interest. Since it’s clear that the latter is unrealistic, we can conclude that political decisions are inherently self-serving.

If you can see by which two statements this was inspired, this may also give more of a clue about their labels :)




I completely disagree with this.
Since people are prone to different opinions, people are often interested in politics rather than their own lives, which is why their actions may completely depend on this or not at all
The rich may be more than calm about it, and the poor do not even think about it
2.
As I already said, people have different opinions and for this reason, both women and men can demand a salary increase
Well, whether they are worthy or not is up to the manager to decide
3.
I completely agree that all people are egoists by nature, but people's desires for self-satisfaction are different and may mean that one person likes to deceive, but another likes to tell only the truth. Yes, the welfare state consists of egoists, but not all egoists want to deceive
